# Django odd boolean bahavior

Tags: django

I have a boolean field for whether or not an item is active:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

It seems pretty straightforward, my template will display items that are active:

```
{% for p in products|dictsortreversed:"id" %}
    {% if p.is_active %}
    <a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">
    {{ p.name }} 
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

For some reason all items are returned even if the field is 0 in the database. When I uncheck the boolean field in the django admin, it updates correctly to 0 in the database, but still shows as being checked in the admin...

It seems like django is reading the field as True, regardless of the boolean value.

Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00)
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, blank=True, default=0.00)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    meta_keywords = models.CharField('Meta Keywords', max_length=255, help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag')
    meta_description = models.CharField('Meta Description', max_length=255, help_text='Content for description meta tag')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    issue_one = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    issue_two = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    issue_three = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'products'
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('catalog_product', (), {'product_slug': self.slug})
```

View:

```
def index(request, template_name="catalog/index.html"):
    """ site home page """
    page_title = 'Visible Language Ordering'
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What do you get if you put `{{ p.is_active }}` before the `{% if %}` tag?

Comment: I'd assume `{{ if p.is_active == True }}` works and it's a case of template language not matching what you'd expect from Python? Personally I'd pass only the objects you want through the context. It's more typical to handle logic in your view.

Comment: @marksweb neither {{ if p.is_active == True }} or {{ if p.is_active == False }} return any values. Doing the filtering in the context makes sense, it's still odd that the admin boolean value is always checked regardless of the actual value being 0 or 1.

Comment: {{ p.is_active }} before the {% if %} tag also returns no value.

Comment: Can you post your model & your view as well? I'll check back in the morning if you can :) I'd be interested to see if the filter on the for loop is the problem as well. What happens if it's just `{% for p in products %}`. Maybe the filter is failing you?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the model and view. Removing the sorting in the for loop doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: What is the database used?

Comment: I set up a basic test of this and mine is working just fine. Whatever is going on I think it must be in another part of your code. What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.7

Comment: Is that your whole view? You are passing `locals()` to the context, but I don't see a query where you assign `products`. Maybe I'm missing something...